# DRF update the nested foreign key of an object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to wrap my head around this for too long already :(
I need the following output for my frontend (specially the `ID` & `name` field in combination):

> {
> "serial": "e3461fb0",
> "shipment": {
> "id": 1,
> "name": "via rotterdam"
> }
> }

model:

```
class Shipment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length = 128)
    date = models.DateField()

class Product(models.Model):
    serial = models.CharField("serial", max_length = 31, unique = True)
    shipment = models.ForeignKey(Shipment, on_delete = models.CASCADE, blank = True, null = True)
```

serializer:

```
class ShipmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Shipment
        fields = ["id", "name",]
        
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    shipment = ShipmentSerializer()

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        print("TEST:", instance, validated_data)
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["serial", "shipment",]    
        lookup_field = "serial"
        read_only_fields = ["serial",]
```

ViewSet:

```
class ProductViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    lookup_field = "serial"
    http_method_names = ["get", "patch", "put"]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.all()
```

my problem here is the following: Lets say a product ist linked to a shipment and what I want now is to update that product by linking it to another shipment by using the `id`. But even in the HTML view of DRF I only get to see the `name` attribute of `shipment`. How can I only show/use the `id` here? I know I could modify the `__str__` method of the model to return a string representation and split it later in the frontend, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

[image]

I was thinking of something like this:

[image]

Comment: You mean that you want to update `shipment` id ?

Comment: exactly. I already played around with adding a `ReadOnlyField` and an `IntegerField` to the `ShipmentSerializer`, but I am not sure this is good way to go:     `id = serializers.IntegerField()`
    `name = serializers.ReadOnlyField()`

Comment: You might want https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested

Answer (score 0):

Id field is what DRF make itself, and it's read-only by default

If you want to update that, you should override this field. Something like:

```py
class ShipmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Shipment
        fields = ["id", "name",]
```